# Is this the only integer point of this curve?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

$\textbf{How to attempt proving that $4x^3-3z^2=1$ has no positive integer solutions?} $

I want to show there is no positive integer solution to this equation other than $(1,1)$. How to do that? Is there a procedure or theorem that could be used here?

The above equation could be transformed to a Mordell Elliptic curve:

$$
t^3-s^2=432
$$
$$
s=36x,\ t=12z
$$
Hence $(s,t)=(36,12)$ is a solution. Also due to Mordell, this has been shown that this type of curve can only have finitely many integer points. How to show there is only one in this case?

My reasoning used Hall's conjecture. But could it be done in any other way?

Comment: What about $(1,-1)$?

Comment: Oh. I forgot to mention positive. I have edited the question.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/a/7979/116794

Comment: More related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296267/a-proof-for-fermats-last-theorem-for-n-3

Comment: Unfortunately, the usual way to prove $t^3-s^2=432$ has only the solutions you know about is by deducing it from the nonexistence of nontrivial solutions to $x^3+y^3=z^3$.

Comment: Haha. This went circular. I derived this equation from $x^3+y^3=z^3$. And the the link that you commented is actually my question which was not at all recieved well. Didn't know validation of proofs is not welcome here. @GerryMyerson

Comment: J. Gebel, A. Pethö and H. G. Zimmer. On Mordell’s equation. Compositio Math. 110 (1998), no. 3, 335–367. They give a systematic method of finding all integer solutions of a Mordell equation and do so for the first few thousands, most likely including yours as well.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Sage will tell you this elliptic curve has torsion subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ and rank $0$, so $s=\pm 36$, $t = 12$ are the only rational solutions.

Comment: Can I ask how does Sage do this? What algorithm does it follow?

Comment: I know that the question to which I linked was yours. Why didn't YOU link to it?

Comment: As I am new here, I am yet to getting used to all features this website provides. How to link by the way?

Comment: I think that this question can easily be dealt with ( as can Fermat's Last Theorem for $n = 3$ ) using the fact that the ring of Eisenstein integers ( $\mathbb{Z}[\omega], \omega = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}})$ has unique factorization.