# Upper bound on number of integral solutions of elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, jacobians

I was studying M. Bhargava Et al's seminal paper titled "[Bounds on 2-torsion in class groups of number fields and integral points on elliptic curves](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02458)"

And came across a very fascinating observation that they made in the paper. Theorem 1.2 states:

The number of integral points on an elliptic curve, E, denoted by $N(E)$ is at most $O_\epsilon(\left| \text{Disc}(E) \right|^{0.1117... + \epsilon})
$

However, following the proof is a little above my pay-grade right now, and I'm not entirely sure as to how they derive the proof, which is given in section 5, Theorems 5.1 and 5.2.

I have a couple of questions:

Is there a fixed value of $\epsilon$ that can act as an upper bound? Am I correct in asserting that $\epsilon$ must be quite small in nature? By quite small, I mean $0.1117... + \epsilon < 1$. The authors state that the earlier upper bound which was given by Venkatesh, Helgott etc. was $O_\epsilon(\left| \text{Disc}(E) \right|^{0.2007... + \epsilon})$. So, can I reasonably assume that $\epsilon + 0.1117... < 0.2007....$

As you can see, I am desperately trying to simply get rid of the $\epsilon$ factor, and would really appreciate a hard upper bound which is not expressed in terms of $\epsilon$ or a constant.

Edit: I know that $N(E) = C(\left| \text{Disc}(E) \right|^{0.1118})$
And would like help in computing $C$. Of course, a weak lower bound is achievable by letting $N(E) = D$, but I would like to know the least number such that $C$ satisfies the condition $\forall E$.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

First, the bound that you cite has been significantly improved by [Alpöge and Ho](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03761v3).  Here is Theorem 1.1 therein.  Let $A,B\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfy $\Delta_{A,B}:=-16(4A^3+16B^2)\neq 0$.   If $\mathscr{E}_{A,B}$ is the affine integral model $y^2 = x^3+Ax+B$ of the associated elliptic curve $E_{A,B}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then the number of solutions $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ to $y^2 = x^3+Ax+B$ is
$$O\Big(2^{\mathrm{rank}(E_{A,B})}\prod_{p^2\mid \Delta_{A,B}}\min\Big(4\Big\lfloor\frac{v_p(\Delta_{A,B})}{2}\Big\rfloor+1,7^{2^7}\Big)\Big),$$
where $v_p(n)$ is the greatest nonnegative integer such that $p^{v_p(n)}\mid n$.  Considering the fact that the number of primes dividing $n$ has maximal order $O((\log n)/\log\log n)$ and normal order $O(\log\log n)$, this bound considerably improves upon the one you mentioned.  Keep in mind that many people now believe that there exists an absolute constant $c>0$ such that $\mathrm{rank}(E_{A,B})<c$, so the rank contribution to this bound is widely believed to be negligible.  If you don't like the big oh notation, see Theorem 1.2 therein for a completely explicit version.

Second, by "Bhargava's seminal paper," I think you really mean "the seminal paper by Bhargava, Shankar, Taniguchi, Thorne, Tsimerman, and Zhao."  Don't forget the other authors, even if they are numerous!

ADDED:  I should also mention the [Helfgott-Venkatesh](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405180) bound

$$e^{O(\omega(\Delta_{A,B}))}1.33^{\mathrm{rank}(E_{A,B})}(\log|\Delta_{A,B}|)^2.$$

Here, $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.
This might be stronger than Alpöge-Ho, depending on the prime factorization of $\Delta_{A,B}$.  We can now take their minimum:

$$\ll\min\Big\{2^{\mathrm{rank}(E_{A,B})}\prod_{p^2\mid \Delta_{A,B}}\min\Big(4\Big\lfloor\frac{v_p(\Delta_{A,B})}{2}\Big\rfloor+1,7^{2^7}\Big),e^{O(\omega(\Delta_{A,B}))}1.33^{\mathrm{rank}(E_{A,B})}(\log|\Delta_{A,B}|)^2\Big\}.$$

Comment: And if you believe the $abc$-conjecture (or alternatively Lang's height lower bound conjecture), then on a quasi-minimal Weierstrass equation (meaning $\gcd(A^3,B^2)$ is 12th power free), there is a bound $$\#E_{A,B}(\mathbb Z)=O(C^{1+\text{rank }E(\mathbb Q)}),$$ where $C$ is an absolute constant. So if you also believe the rank upper bound conjecture that you alluded to, there should be an absolute bound for $\#E_{A,B}(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: The number of primes dividing $n$ has maximal order $O(\log n/\log\log n)$ instead of $O(\log n)$.

Comment: @GHfromMO Indeed!  It's now fixed, thanks.

Comment: @2734364041 Thank you for your response. Two questions: Firstly, isn't theorem 1.2 related to the number of $S$ integral points over an elliptic curve instead of just the integral points? Secondly, why do people believe $\mathrm{rank}(E_{A,B})<c$? Didn't Prof. Elkies discover a curve with rank $28$?

Comment: @Navvye  Theorem 1.1 follows as a consequence of Theorem 1.2.  You are welcome to read their paper.  There are lots of reasons to believe that the rank is absolutely bounded, just like there are lots of reasons to believe otherwise.  There is a lot of literature out there for you to read on the matter; I do not know of a good summarizing paper.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one last question: Do you know of any papers where an explicit bound for the number of solutions is given in terms of the discriminant (apart from the one I mentioned)? Either way, thank you very much for your response!

Comment: @Navvye Theorem 1.2 in Alpöge-Ho is completely explicit, no big-oh's at all.  If you want something completely explicit without rank dependence, you'll need to work incredibly hard to make Bhargava-Shankar-Taniguchi-Thorne-Tsimerman-Zhao explicit.  That is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a question that actually needs the most explicit bound possible, the best I've found is $10h_{3}(-108d)$ where $h_3(-108d)$ is the class number for cubic form with a discriminant $d$ — and since we don't have an estimate on the bound of the rank of elliptic curves, I don't know what to do.

In case you're interested, the actual problem I'm solving is how many elliptic curves exist such that $y^2 = x^3 + D$ has exactly $D$ solutions

Answer (score 2):

You can take any $\epsilon>0$ you like. For example, by taking $\epsilon = 0.1118 - 0.1117...$ we get a bound $C|Disc(E)|^{0.1118}$ for some constant $C$. This is an "upper bound which is not expressed in terms of $\epsilon$", as requested.

Comment: Thank you so much. How exactly should I decide which $C$ to use? Is this related to Hall's conjecture?

Comment: @Navvye It seems you are asking a different question in the above comment. If so, please ask a new question. I believe Bogdan has given you a satisfactory answer to your original question, which means that you should accept his answer (after a few days to see if someone can give you a more insightful answer, but I doubt that's possible within the scope of the original question).

Comment: I've edited the original question to reflect the change in the question if that's alright

Comment: @Navvye what you are asking for is for an explicit bound on $C = C(\varepsilon)$. It seems that the methods used to prove the theorems in that paper are effective, so in principle such a bound can be deduced. However, the authors have made no effort to compute the implied constant, and for someone else to do so is a major task, having to trace through not only the arguments in that paper but also the cited papers. Is there any specific application you have in mind that would require such precision, or do you just need to know that $C$ is effectively computable?

Comment: Yes, I need to know the explicit bound $C$ in order to do some computations about specific solutions to Mordell Equations. If I have to find the constant, how would I go about doing it? Also, what evidence points to $C$ being effectively computable? I know it doesn't depend upon Roth's theorem, which is a good sign..

Comment: For a specific example, you can do much better in practice. Look at Nigel Smart's "The algorithmic resolution of diophantine equations." Chapter VII.4, or other suggestions given [in these answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7907/how-to-find-all-integer-points-on-an-elliptic-curve)

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Thank you for your comment - I'm not looking at a specific example however, i'm looking at the general class of mordell equations